# Rails: dependent: :destroy - How does this work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, dependencies, associations

In an example where there is an association of Owner that is as fellows:

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buildings, dependent: :destroy 
end
```

The other side of relationship:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
end
```

If I were to delete an Owner, would it destroy the associated Building(s) as well? How can I specify a dependent relationship so that the owner and primary key is no longer associated with any Building(s) if I delete an Owner?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want `:nullify`.  See the Rails docs for `has_many`.

`:dependent` controls what happens to the associated objects when their owner is destroyed. Note that these are implemented as callbacks, and Rails executes callbacks in order. Therefore, other similar callbacks may affect the :dependent behavior, and the :dependent behavior may affect other callbacks.

`:destroy` causes all the associated objects to also be destroyed.

`:delete_all` causes all the associated objects to be deleted directly from the database (so callbacks will not be executed).

`:nullify` causes the foreign keys to be set to NULL. Callbacks are not executed.

`:restrict_with_exception` causes an exception to be raised if there are any associated records.

`:restrict_with_error` causes an error to be added to the owner if there are any associated objects.

If using with the `:through` option, the association on the join model must be a `belongs_to`, and the records which get deleted are the join records, rather than the associated records.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it will delete the associated buildings as dependent `:destroy` specified.
2. If you want to keep the building record, I suggest you use a join table, so that when owner is deleted, only the record in the join table is deleted.